# ¿Por qué al usar mat datepicker quita un dia a la fecha que muestra y como darle formato a la fecha que muestra?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-datepicker

Estoy usando mat datepicker y al momento de mostrar la fecha que obtengo del servicio, le quita un día

esta es la fecha que muestra la base que es de tipo Date

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es mi formulario

```
 <button mat-button (click)="guardar()">Guardar</button>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="idControl">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.idControl}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="cveEstado">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ESTADO </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-select [(value)]="element.cveEstado" (selectionChange)="cambiarEstado($event.value, element)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let estatus of estadoModel" [value]="estatus.cveEstado" 
            [ngClass]="{'text-red':estatus.cveEstado=='ERR', 'text-blue':estatus.cveEstado=='INP'}">
              {{estatus.descripcion}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

 
    <ng-container matColumnDef="comentario">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> COMENTARIO </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [value]="element.comentario" (keyup)="changeValue($event.target)">
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="horaInicio">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> HORA </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.horaInicio}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaRegistro">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> FECHAREGISTRO </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [value]="element.fechaRegistro">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

y asi es como se muestra en la tabla, como le puedo dar el formato para que salga como en la base y que no me quite un día? además como le puedo hacer para que el calendario solo aparezca en las filas donde si tiene datos , y no se pinte en todas, y como recuperar el valor de la fecha cuando se seleccione otra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi component.ts, donde uso el `this.dataAdapter.setLocale('es-MX');`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Control } from './Control';
import { ControlService } from './control.service';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Estado } from './Estado.ts';
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'prueba-angular-material';
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['idControl', 'cveEstado', 'comentario', 'horaInicio','fechaRegistro'];
  estadoModel: Estado[]= [];
  control: Control[] = [];
  estadoSeleccionado: any;
  idSeleccionado: string = '';
  comentIngresado: string ='';
  fechaIngresada: string ='';


  constructor(private controlService: ControlService, private dataAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>) {
    this.dataAdapter.setLocale('es-MX');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerLista();
    this.obtenerListaEstados();
  }

  dataSource: any;
  private obtenerLista() {
    this.controlService.obtenerLista().subscribe(response => {
      this.control = response.data;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.control);

    })
  }

  private obtenerListaEstados() {
    this.controlService.obtenerEstados().subscribe(response => {
      this.estadoModel = response.data;
    })
  }

  cambiarEstado(valor: Event, row: any) {
    this.estadoSeleccionado = valor;
    this.idSeleccionado = row.idControl;
    console.log(" ID SELECC " +this.idSeleccionado );
    console.log(" ESTADO SELECC " +this.estadoSeleccionado );
  }

  changeValue(e: any) {
    console.log(" INPUT  " +e.value);
    this.comentIngresado = e.value;
    this.fechaIngresada = e.value
  }

  guardar(){
    if(this.comentIngresado == "" &&  this.idSeleccionado ==""){
      alert("No se han modificado campos");
    }else{
      console.log(" ENTRA ELSE  " +this.comentIngresado + " "+this.idSeleccionado);
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Tal vez por la zona horaria. La fecha que muestra la DB estará en una zona horaria y la que muestra tu vista estará en otra zona horaria.

Comment: Lo mismo, si el campo en BD no tiene zona horaria y lo guarda en la zona horaria del servidor de BD, va a verse todo mal cuando lo consultes y lo pintes en el navegador, que por defecto usa la zona horaria de la terminal (a menos que alguna librería en tu frontend ponga oootro estándar). No asumas ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yo le sume un día al darle a aceptar (para que el usuario no viese nada) con este código.

```
this.dia =  new Date(this.form.value.fechaNacimiento);
this.dia = new Date( this.dia.setDate(this.dia.getDate() +1));
this.form.patchValue({
  fechaNacimiento: new Date(this.dia)
})
```